# Quantum channels and error correction research groups

Tags: error-correction, research

I am wondering which are the top universities or research groups through the world that are doing research in the topic of quantum error correction or quantum channels (decoherence noise models). I think this is interesting in order to know which are the main tendencies that the quantum community is following concerning those fields.

Comment: Here's a annual conference held last year [qec19](http://qec19.iopconfs.org/home) that is dedicated to quantum error correction. You can look through the schedule to find topics/people that are currently being researched. Videos of all the talks are also on youtube [qec19-playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgLkEJ3SUJUS05I_INGLpkNcaWQdXfCeo)